# What's the most efficient way to take up to the last n elements of a list

Tags: haskell

To clarify :  I want all the elements but the last n

Reading some answers on stackoverflow I get the impression that using length on lists is inadvisable. So is there better way to do this than `take (length xs - n) xs`?

Comment: take `(length xs - n) xs` would give you all the elements but the last `n`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**. You first drop `n` elements from the list, then walk over the two lists concurrently and when the you hit the end of the list with the dropped version of the list, then you return the list of the "iterator" over the entire list:

```
takeLast :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
takeLast n ls = go (drop n ls) ls
    where go [] ls = ls
          go (_:xs) ~(_:ys) = go xs ys
```

This thus works because the first "iterator" is *n* steps ahead. So if it hits the end of the list, the second iterator is *n* steps behind the end of the list.

For example:

```
Prelude> takeLast 2 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[0,2]
Prelude> takeLast 3 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[3,0,2]
Prelude> takeLast 4 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[1,3,0,2]
Prelude> takeLast 5 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[5,1,3,0,2]
```

We can also drop the last `n` elements in a similar way:

```
dropLast :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropLast n ls = go (drop n ls) ls
    where go [] _ = []
          go (_:xs) ~(y:ys) = y : go xs ys
```

For example:

```
Prelude> dropLast 2 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[1,4,2,5,1,3]
Prelude> dropLast 3 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[1,4,2,5,1]
Prelude> dropLast 4 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[1,4,2,5]
Prelude> dropLast 5 [1,4,2,5,1,3,0,2]
[1,4,2]
```

If we operate on an infinite list, then `dropLast` will still yield elements, whereas if we would use `take (length ls - n) ls`, it would get stuck in an infinite loop.

We can, as [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390393/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-take-up-to-the-last-n-elements-of-a-list/64390524?noredirect=1#comment113864210_64390524) use `zipWith` for this:

```
dropLast :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropLast n xs = zipWith const xs (drop n xs)
```

Here we let `zipWith` iterate over both lists, and we use `const` to each time return the element of the first list.

Comment: This takes last N elements whereas OP seems to what all but last N elements.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: well the title says "take up the last *n* elements", the code fragment in the question seems to indicate dropping the last n elements.

Comment: There is a standardish trick for `dropLast`: `dropLast n xs = zipWith const xs (drop n xs)` or if you are feeling cheeky `dropLast n = zipWith const <*> drop n`. Seems like there could be an analog for `takeLast` if we had `stripPrefixBy`, but the standard library doesn't include that variant of `stripPrefix`. Too bad.